# Laravel 5 - link_to_route() method making my route parameters to change into Query String by adding "?" at the end

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, helper

After hours of searching I still could not find my answer regarding `L5`.

What my issue is :

I want to make a link something like this:

```
localhost:800/songs/you-drive-me-crazy
```

BUT what is get is:

```
localhost:800/songs?you-drive-me-crazy
```

my route parameter is changing into query string.

//routes.php

```
$router->bind('songs', function($slug)
{
return App\Song::where('slug', $slug)->first();
});


$router->get('songs', ['as' => 'songs.index', 'uses' =>    'SongsController@index'] );

$router->get('songs/{songs}', ['as' => 'songs.show', 'uses' => 'SongsController@show'] );
```

I am using:

```
{!! link_to_route('songs.index', $song->title, [$song->slug])  !!}
```

I have tried everything but not succeeded yet,your suggestion may be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: yes, L5 == Laravel 5

Comment: try this {!! link_to_route('songs.index', $song->title,['songs'=>$song->slug])  !!}

Comment: one more thing have you set your base url properly in app.php ?

Answer (score 11):

Your usage of link_to_route is incorrect:

```
{!! link_to_route('songs.index', [$song->title, $song->slug])  !!}
```

The first parameter is the route name, the second parameter is an array of route parameters, preferably using key value. Because you did not show your defined route, it's hard to guess what this associative array should look like:

```
{!! link_to_route('songs.index', ['title'=>$song->title, 'slug'=>$song->slug])  !!}
```

Also I advise you to use the documented functions: `route()`, see: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/helpers#urls

A correctly requested route using `route()`:

```
{!! route('songs.index', ['title'=>$song->title, 'slug'=>$song->slug])  !!}
```

A properly formatted route would then be:

```
Route::get('songs/{title}/{slug}', ['as' => 'songs.index', 'uses' => 'SomeController@index']);
```

This will result in a URL like: `http://localhost:800/songs/you-drive-me-crazy/slug`

If you only want to add the title to the URL but not the slug, use a route like this:

```
Route::get('songs/{title}', ['as' => 'songs.index', 'uses' => 'SomeController@index']);
```

This will result in a URL like: `http://localhost:800/songs/you-drive-me-crazy/?slug=slug`

Using

```
Route::get('songs/{slug}', ['as' => 'songs.index', 'uses' => 'SomeController@index']);
```

The URL will be like: `http://localhost:800/songs/you-drive-me-crazy/?title=title` assuming the slug now is `you-drive-me-crazy`

Any added parameter in a `route()` call will be added as a GET parameter if it's not existing in the route definition.

Comment: second parameter is the text that appears as a link. it cannot be an array

Comment: what is your routes.php definition

Comment: get('songs', ['as' => 'songs.index', 'uses' => 'SongsController@index'] );
get('songs/{songs}', ['as' => 'songs.show', 'uses' => 'SongsController@show'] );

Comment: you have to define the possible parameters too; `get('songs/{title}/{slug}'..` see: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#route-parameters

Comment: but right now its about the link that is not generating correctly.

Comment: that has to do with the route definition, if you leave out a parameter, any added parameter is added as a GET parameter instead of being added to the url

Comment: Ah i see you don't want to add the slug, but only the title to the url

Comment: Actually, I just want to add the "SLUG" to my link, like this : localhost:800/songs/you-drive-me-crazy - but my slug appears as a Query string with "?" attached. m I doing wrong with my routes?

Comment: Update the question with what you have now. Your feedback is hardly of any use.

Comment: I have made little changes to my routes.php `$router->bind('songs', function($slug)
{
    return App\Song::where('slug', $slug)->first();
});


$router->get('songs', ['as' => 'songs.index', 'uses' => 'SongsController@index'] );
$router->get('songs/{songs}', ['as' => 'songs.show', 'uses' => 'SongsController@show'] );`

Comment: Update your question with properly formatted code please.

Comment: Also your route parameter is now plural songs did you also use that when calling the route function?

Answer (score 2):

fixed it, thanks for your great concerns and suggestions.

I was linking to wrong route here:

```
`{!! link_to_route('songs.index', $song->title, [$song->slug])  !!}`
```

now, I changed it as :

```
`{!! link_to_route('songs.show', $song->title, [$song->slug])  !!}`
```

and it did the trick.